# Changing the "Tab Page" Color in FF

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When you click `New Tab (+)` in Firefox you display a list of your most viewed pages. (version 13+). I have changed this to not display but the page was entirely white. Before the page was black (I believe it was set that way by my Appearance Add-On)

How can I change the color of the new tab page in Firefox (I am using version 13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on and create the following style:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url("about:blank")
{

    body
    {
        background-color: ... !important;
    }

}
```

Where `...` is a valid CSS color value.

Comment: Almost 6 years later, this doesn't seem to work with the latest version of Firefox (58) :(